# Searching with MySQL database and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search page in PHP which i can enter a string to search.
Also I have written a page which displays the results which matches with the string in the database.
SQL query is

```
$query = "select * from table_name WHERE Name LIKE '$srch' || Last LIKE '$srch' || email LIKE '$srch' || comment LIKE '$srch'";
```

If the search string is "John David", I would like to show every record that contains
either "John" or "David" rather than only showing results that have both "John David", since I have records like John Samuel,David Grecco, Jennifer Davidson etc

Answer (score 2):

You might want to do a MySQL FULLTEXT search in boolean mode. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Edit: To elaborate, you query would become:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 
          MATCH (Name,Last,email,comment) 
          AGAINST('$srch' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

If that does work for you then you will want to add a FULLTEXT index on the columns you are searching.

Answer (score 0):

you can explode your string into words and do search on each of them individually.

```
$where_clause = "";
foreach($words as $key=>$word){
  $or = "";
  if (isset($words[$key+1])){
   $or = " OR";
  }
  $where_clause = "Name LIKE '$srch' || Last LIKE '$srch' || email LIKE '$srch' || comment LIKE '$srch' {$or}";
}
```

I think this would be correct

Comment: yes..i exploded the string into array. How can I compare it with each value in the database? Can you please post some sample code here

Comment: you can either generate WHERE clause with OR statemanet on each word. or run your query for each word and then combine results. I'll post an example in a minute

Comment: Got an error like Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: you must explode your string into $words variable. I havent written that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it personally, but you might have luck with mySQL's [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator.

From mySQL's [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

> **Regular Expression Operators  expr NOT REGEXP pat, expr NOT RLIKE pat**
>
> This is the same as NOT (expr REGEXP pat).
>
> expr REGEXP pat, expr RLIKE pat
>
> Performs a pattern match of a string expression expr against a pattern
>   pat. The pattern can be an extended regular expression, the syntax for
>   which is discussed later in this section. Returns 1 if expr matches
>   pat; otherwise it returns 0. If either expr or pat is NULL, the result
>   is NULL. RLIKE is a synonym for REGEXP, provided for mSQL
>   compatibility.
>
> The pattern need not be a literal string. For example, it can be
>   specified as a string expression or table column.
>
> Note Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example,
>   “\n” to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that
>   you use in your REGEXP strings.
>
> REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.
>
> mysql> SELECT 'Monty!' REGEXP '.*';
>           -> 1 mysql> SELECT 'new*\n*line' REGEXP 'new\*.\*line';
>           -> 1 mysql> SELECT 'a' REGEXP 'A', 'a' REGEXP BINARY 'A';
>           -> 1  0 mysql> SELECT 'a' REGEXP '^[a-d]';
>           -> 1 REGEXP and RLIKE use the character set and collations of the arguments when deciding the type of a character and performing the
>   comparison.